# invalid stored block lengths java.io.IOException: invalid stored block lengths

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

I have one zip that contains 2 JSON files. When I process those files I got the following error. The first file is processed properly when it comes to the second file which throws **ZipException**.
How can I fix this?

My code,

```
private Path archivePath = Paths.get("src/test/resources/data/files.zip";

public void uploadData() throws IOException {

FileSystem fileFS = FileSystems.newFileSystem(archivePath,(ClassLoader) null);

String[] pathNames = {"file_1.json","file_2.json"};

for(String pathName : pathNames) {

    //unzip files
    Path path = fileFS.getPath(pathName);

    Request request = new Request("POST","/_bulk");

    RequestOptions.Builder options = RequestOptions.DEFAULT.toBuilder();
    options.addHeader("Content-Type","application/x-ndjson");

    request.setOptions(options);

    request.setEntity(new InputStreamEntity(Files.newInputStream(path)));

    Response response = client.performRequest(request);
    assertResponseSuccessful(response,false);
}
```

Error:

```
invalid stored block lengths
java.io.IOException: invalid stored block lengths
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.extractAndWrapCause(RestClient.java:828)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:248)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:235)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:134)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:597)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:766)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:587)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:28)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:425)
    at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil.lambda$execute$0(ThreadUtil.java:68)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid stored block lengths
    at java.base/java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:165)
    at java.base/java.nio.channels.Channels$ReadableByteChannelImpl.read(Channels.java:388)
    at org.apache.http.nio.entity.EntityAsyncContentProducer.produceContent(EntityAsyncContentProducer.java:67)
    at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.BasicAsyncRequestProducer.produceContent(BasicAsyncRequestProducer.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.MainClientExec.produceContent(MainClientExec.java:262)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.produceContent(DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.java:140)
    at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.outputReady(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:249)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalRequestExecutor.outputReady(InternalRequestExecutor.java:96)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.produceOutput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:290)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onOutputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:86)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onOutputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:39)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.outputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:145)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.writable(BaseIOReactor.java:187)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:341)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)
    ... 1 more
```

Any inputs here are really be appreciated.